# SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/abrtd from create access on the lnk_file .lock

Tags: centos-7

I keep getting this error in the notification tray on my **CentOS 7** desktop. Following is a screenshot of the SELinux Alert Browser.

[image]

I tried executing the following command given in the solution tab of this window but it also didn't work.

```
sudo ausearch -c 'abrtd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-abrtd
```

returned the following error

```
could not write output file: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'my-abrtd.te'
```

How can this be resolved?

---

**Update #1**

I was able to execute the command given in the solution tab of this window. The issue was that the pipeline command didn't have permission. Following are the commands I ran.

```
$ sudo ausearch -c 'abrtd' --raw | sudo audit2allow -M my-abrtd
$ sudo semodule -i my-abrtd.pp
```

But this didn't solve the issue. I'm still getting the same error.

---

**Update #2**

I changed the SELinux mode for `enforcing` to `permissive` in the config file `/etc/selinux/config`. This time I got the following error.

[image]